# Java : Central Application

Tags: java, jar

I'm currently developing multiple project management applications for my team, and distributing these as JARs, which is OK for now. But I was asked to make a central application to launch them.

Basically a small app, with a button for each app I already made, and when you click the button, it launches the corresponding app. I managed to do everything except one point.
I include my JARs in the buildpath, then launch them by creating an instance of the Main class. This actually works, but when I want to close one window, it closes all of them....

Anyone got an idea on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ! I had this in each app Main class (extending `JFrame`) :

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I changed it to :

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Now this works.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the new application in a different VM by launching a new process. Something like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "EXECUTABLE.JAR").start()
```

If Java is in your path.

Comment: This way, can I launch JARs located in my build path ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your build path. Are you embedding the jars for the applications in your launcher's jar?

Comment: Yes, to simplify the distribution process

Comment: In that case you can do something like this to launch one of them as a separate process: new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", "LAUNCHER.JAR", "your.package.MAINCLASS").start().

Answer (score 1):

Are launching using another Java app? If so, the window close event might trigger a System.exit(); Could you post some code?

Also consider using Webstart and providing the links to the applications in a web page.
Thus users could open that page and Webstart would download and start the app.

Comment: The question is whether this application launcher is really necessary. If this is a hard requirement, then ok. Look for the `System.exit()` (or catch the window close event) or try Russ' approach.